# IBM MQ - I can't subscribe to topic using wildcard syntax

Tags: ibm-mq

I have the following topics which are created on IBM MQ docker version:

> dev/test/sys1 dev/test/sys2

I am trying to create subscriber from XMS .NET APIs using the following code:

> destination = sessionWMQ.CreateTopic("dev/test/#");

The following exception appears, it is related to permissions based "Reason: 2035", but I am not able to figure out what is the permission I have to grant and from where

> XMSException caught: IBM.XMS.IllegalStateException: Failed to
> subscribe to topic dev/# using MQSUB. There may have been a problem
> creating the subscription due to it being used by another message
> consumer. Make sure any message consumers using this subscription are
> closed before trying to create a new subscription under the same name.
> Please see the linked exception for more information.

Comment: I found the solution, I had to grant the user permission on the following system topic

SYSTEM.BASE.TOPIC

Comment: For testing purpose it is OK to grant permission to SYSTEM.BASE.TOPIC. Giving permission to SYSTEM.BASE.TOPIC means you are letting every one subscribe to any topic under the base topic. It will be a security concern. You need to create your topic object and grant requirement permission.

Comment: Ah - comments - well never mind - I have written up my answer before seeing the comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you receive an error 2035 (MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED) there will be a corresponding message in the queue manager error log `AMQERR01.LOG`. It will say something like this:-

```
AMQ8009: Entity 'mqgusr1' has insufficient authority to access topic string
'dev/test/#'.

EXPLANATION:
The specified entity is not authorized to access the required topic. The
following requested permissions are unauthorized: sub
ACTION:
Ensure that the correct level of authority has been set for this entity against
appropriate topic objects, or ensure that the entity is a member of a privileged
group.
```

Specifically this error message will tell you the user id, the object name, and the missing authorization. Using this information, you can **almost** construct the command you need. You do need one more peice of information and that is the group name that the user is in that you wish to grant the authority on. It is always recommended that you use group names and not user names when granting authorities or you may end up with too many authorities to manage, or perhaps worse, more users than you expected gaining the authority you granted as a result of the primary group of the user being something like 'staff'.

Here's the command, assuming that 'mqgusr1' in my error message, is in the group 'mqgapp' and that group is suitable for being granted authority to subscribe to a topic.

```
SET AUTHREC PROFILE(SYSTEM.BASE.TOPIC) OBJTYPE(TOPIC) GROUP('mqgapp') AUTHADD(SUB)
```

It is worth mentioning at this point that adding topic related authorities to the SYSTEM.BASE.TOPIC results in the group in question being able to use **any** topic available - this object represents the root of the topic tree. If you wish to restrict access to only certain parts of the topic tree (recommended), then you should instead create a topic object for the section of the topic tree you want to use, and then grant authority there instead, thus the following commands:

```
SET AUTHREC PROFILE(SYSTEM.BASE.TOPIC) OBJTYPE(TOPIC) GROUP('mqgapp') AUTHRMV(SUB)
DEFINE TOPIC(DEV.TEST) TOPICSTR('dev/test')
SET AUTHREC PROFILE(DEV.TEST) OBJTYPE(TOPIC) GROUP('mqgapp') AUTHADD(SUB)
```

Comment: I find it better to do something like `DELETE AUTHREC PROFILE(SYSTEM.BASE.TOPIC) OBJTYPE(TOPIC) GROUP('mqgapp')` rather than `AUTHRMV` the only permissions.   The difference is the record is removed with `DELETE` vs leaving behind a record with no permissions.  If I really want a record with no permission take away some authority from more specific objects I like to leave at least some permission such as `INQ` or `DSP`, this allows `amqoamd` and `dmpmqaut` with the `-e` to still have something to display.

Comment: Hi @JoshMc, yes this is certainly more appropriate if you know that you want to remove all the authorities and not just one. Unfortunately, I cannot know whether this is true or not as I only know a small part of the system that has been mentioned in the question, and it would be unwise to suggest something that deletes more than is needed in an answer.

Comment: I thought your intent was to undo the "SET AUTHREC" you had provided earlier in the question.

Comment: @JoshMc, yes it was, but I can't tell if that group had other permissions on that topic which using the DELETE AUTHREC command would remove. I just thought it hazardous to write an answer which could undo more than it did.

Comment: Thanks @MoragHughson, but when I removed the permission from SYSTEM.BASE.TOPIC I can't subscribe to the topic using wildcard scheme

destination = sessionWMQ.CreateTopic("dev/test/#");

I got the following exception

MQ8009W: Entity 'app' has insufficient authority to access topic string 'dev/test/#'. [CommentInsert1(app), CommentInsert2(dev/test/#), CommentInsert3(sub)]

I grant the user app all available permissions on dev/ topic and dev/test topics but it is not working

Comment: Hi @IsmailEnjreny - that suggests that the authorities are not set on appropriate topic objects in that case. If you issue the MQSC command DISPLAY TPSTATUS('dev/test') ADMIN and check that the topic object name shown is the one you are granting permissions on.

Comment: The MQSC command shown the following results: TOPICSTR(dev/est/) ADMIN(DEV.TEST), which means the permission is granted successfully, also I did the same check from MQ Explorer, but still I can't use wildcard subscription from MXS.NET Client

Comment: @IsmailEnjreny - is that a copy and paste error, or is the TOPICSTR really dev/est? Because if it is that would be the problem.

Comment: @MoragHughson - "TOPICSTR(dev/est/) ADMIN(DEV.TEST)" is copy past output from "DISPLAY TPSTATUS('dev/test') ADMIN" command

Comment: @IsmailEnjreny - so your application is trying to subscribe to the topic string 'dev/test' and you have granted authority to a topic object representing the topic string 'dev/est'? Can you delete and recreate the TOPIC(DEV.TEST) so that it contains the TOPICSTR('dev/test') and then reapply the authorities.